# To display this page, Firefox must send information that will repeat any action (such as a search or order confirmation) that was performed earlier

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Hey I am getting this confirmation by firefox.

```
To display this page, Firefox must send information that will repeat any action
(such as a search or order confirmation) that was performed earlier.
```

Anybody knows what is this confirmation for?

And how to get rid out of this?

Comment: Better answers are given in a question that was posted later:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12622019

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This happens when you refresh a page that is the result of a POST request (as opposed to a GET request).

To avoid it, you can use the [POST/redirect/GET pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).

Answer (score 15):

Try to change your request type from POST to GET.

If not possible to change the request type,
For reloading the page, try using:

```
window.location=window.location;
```

Instead of

```
window.location.reload();
```

As suggested in answer to the question [preventing firefox reload confirmation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12622019/preventing-firefox-reload-confirmation)

Worked very well in Firefox, Chrome..

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue on a website I made.  I ended up doing all of the backend work, then using this code:

```
header("Location: webpage.php", true, 303);
```

This clears out any post data and redirects the page so reloading will not cause that message anymore.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening when you refresh a page to which some POST data was sent (for example, when you have completed a form). This question is asking you if you want to re-send that data so, if you made a search the searched term will be sent again to the server. This is dangerous when you completed a form where you have ordering something, so refreshing the page and resending the data will make a new order in that site.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the request to the page was from a `POST`.

You should use the [Post/Redirect/Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Changed the method request type from POST to GET in my search form and got rid of the confirmation box..

Answer (score 0):

replace the existing code "top.location.reload() " with code "top.location.href=top.location.href"
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/695164

Answer (score 0):

The way Firefox is giving warning ; saying you're re-submitting form with post method.

below workaround worked for me.

```
<form id="yourDummyform" method="post" action="yourPostActionURL?var1=val1&var2=val2">

<!--or some hidden variables here -->

</form>
```

on Success of ajax call or some event 
do

```
$("#yourDummyform").submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have overcome this problem for my requirement like this. 
I have added following code after form submit

```
document.getElementById("frmtbl").submit();
document.getElementById("nxt").click();
document.getElementById("frst").click();
```

nxt and frst are links for next and first page on the navigation bar.
Others may get clue.