# Preventing Firefox reload confirmation

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome, reload, onbeforeunload

I'm displaying certain records in an editable table. The user when attempts to reload the table while editing a record a pop up comes warning the record about the unsaved data.

```
function cancelProcess()
{
    if(noEditedRecords !=0)//number of edited records in the table
    {
        var processConfirmation = confirm("You've Edited "+ noEditedRecords +" Records. Are You sure to undo the Changes made?");

        if (processConfirmation ==true){
            window.onbeforeunload = null;
            window.location.reload();
        }
    }
}
```

When he clicks OK to reload the page, Firefox prompts as

> To display this page, Firefox must send information that will repeat any action (such as a search or order confirmation) that was performed earlier.

And when opening the same page in Chrome, no such prompt appears.

I tried to avoid this by setting `window.onbeforeunload = null;`, but still the prompt window appears there.

Also I tried by changing Firefox configuration:

`browser.sessionstore.postdata`

*Changed 0 to 1* as suggested in Mozilla support page.

But nothing worked.. How do I prevent the prompt?

Comment: I have a feeling that what you need is different from what you're asking. Any chance you can show your code?

Comment: @JesseJ Have included the code ..

Answer (score 39):

Using

```
window.location=window.location;
```

Instead of

```
location.reload();
```

work for me.

Comment: Works perfect for me.!!

Comment: You saved my day ;)

Answer (score 3):

With Firefox 82 (mac) I have found (big chunk of luck) the right parameter to change:

set   **dom.confirm_repost.testing.always_accept**  to true

and the confirmation request window will disapear.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this, and sent data as only **GET** instead of **POST**,

It my not suit all needs but it works....

I was also using **location.reload();**

Answer (score 2):

The behavior is correct. According to w3schools reload has a parameter **forceGet** that is default false, and as a result if you have a POST submit, the the browser will try to resend that POST data, and as such, it needs your confirmation. Firefox does this right, and google chrome behaves like it has a default of true for **forceGet**

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_reload.asp

while `window.location=window.location` or `window.location=window.location.href` (or any other variation of this) works most of the time, when you are using an anchor url like http://www.google.com#test will not be refreshed with this method. The browser will do the exact same thing as it will do when you are already on google.com and you change the url by adding #test. The browser will just try to locate the anchor tag in the page that has the name test, and scroll down to it, without refreshing your browser.

The solution that works in this case as well as any other case I encountered would be `window.location.reload(true);`

Hope this helps,

Alexandru Cosoi

Answer (score 1):

```
window.opener.location.href = window.opener.location;
```

I've found the decision [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/55968/Reload-page-for-refresh-data-without-retry-cancel)

(Tested on Firefox 32 and Chrome 38 successfully.)

Answer (score 0):

The way to avoid that prompt is to not create a situation where a user is trying to reload a POST result page.

Comment: Is there any way to restore the window to previous state other than reloading it?

Comment: You can use Javascript and do AJAX.

Comment: @Emmi That depends on what sort of previous state you want.  Just focusing URL bar and hitting enter, for example, _may_ do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
setTimeout (function () {
    window.location.reload();
},0);
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution worked for me:

-> convert the POST request to GET request.

-> location.reload() to  window.location=window.location

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using location.reload(), use location.href = "file_where_you_are.php";
This prevents to post twice, preventing also the message to appear.

Comment: This is essentially the same as [the existing top-voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18321086).