# Suddenly starts receiving alert when trying to login to wordpress admin panel

Tags: php, wordpress, firefox, iis

Suddenly starts receiving alert when trying to login to wordpress admin panel. Hosting is on IIS server. It is type of alert prompt box given by firefox browser only with following text:

```
"To display this page, Firefox must send information that will repeat any action (such as a search or order confirmation) that was performed earlier".
```

Wordpress admin login is the core functionality of wordpress. I didn't make any change in core files. Please suggest how can i solve this.

I already checked this one ([To display this page, Firefox must send information that will repeat any action (such as a search or order confirmation) that was performed earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9871705/to-display-this-page-firefox-must-send-information-that-will-repeat-any-action))!

Anybody please help?

No change did on server side. It was working before that fine.

> Updated:- When i am trying to login via chrome browser then in the
>   title of tab, its displaying "You are being redirected.". Its
>   reloading the page many times. But i am unable to troubleshoot the
>   same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [To display this page, Firefox must send information that will repeat any action (such as a search or order confirmation) that was performed earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9871705/to-display-this-page-firefox-must-send-information-that-will-repeat-any-action)

Comment: I'm not downvote on your question.

Comment: @KrisRoofe thanks for your reply. But its just core wordpress files, i haven't done anything with them. But how it can come sudden? How can i troubleshoot this without modifying any core file?

Comment: if you do not want to change the code file then you could run chrome with this parameter disable-prompt-on-repost. for firefox, you could  try In the URL window of firefox type about:config, Change this setting in firefox browser.sessionstore.postdata,Change from 0 to 1. usefull links: [link1](https://support.mozilla.org/bm/questions/1036883#answer-666159) ,[link2](https://forums.asp.net/post/2696037.aspx) or you could try to delete the browser cookie.

Comment: @JalpaPanchal thanks for reply. I have tried using deleting all the cookies but doesn't working. Also we can't tell customers to change their firefox browser settings. Any other alternative?

Comment: the only way you need to change your code.